# C++ space in char array is equal to \0?

Tags: c++, arrays, space

as you may have understood from the title, my question is that if it's true that in char array c++ recognizes space as /0 ? If so, is there any way to make it ignore spaces as /0?

Comment: \0 is the identifier for the end of a string

Comment: Do you even realize that you typed `\0` in the title and `/0` in the text? Are you aware that `/` and `\ ` are different characters? So are `'\0'` and `' '`, but a modest amount of attention to detail is indispensable for programming.

Comment: ye ye.. calm down, my mistake.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short answer is *no*. And so is the long answer.